# what is the difference between a Maven Module and a Maven Project

Tags: maven, maven-2, maven-3

I am trying to understand the difference between a Maven Module and Maven Project. Which is what and where I should one?
Thanks

Comment: Both are same But in module we need to specify Parent of Module. is Possible duplication of [Link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890341/maven-module-vs-project-eclipse-m2eclipse-plugin)

Comment: IMHO, http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890341/maven-module-vs-project-eclipse-m2eclipse-plugin is specific to m2eclipse, whereas this question isn't.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Maven "Module" vs "Project" (Eclipse, m2eclipse plugin)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890341/maven-module-vs-project-eclipse-m2eclipse-plugin)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

a maven module is like a maven "sub-project".  a maven project includes 1 or more modules.  more info [here](http://maven.apache.org/guides/mini/guide-multiple-modules.html).

Typically, a module generates a single artifact (jar, war, zip, etc), although this is not always true.