# How to migrate a standalone java project in to maven project using m2e

Tags: maven

I'm new to maven, and I am in the process of migrating all my eclipse projects to m2e projects.  I'm having these three usage questions:

1) Currently, I've two standalone java projects that are being referenced by two different web projects.  At first, I was thinking about creating those two standalone java projects as maven modules.  But my understanding is that a module can only have one parent project.  So, how can they be referenced in two different web projects?  Would this means that I would have to create these two java projects as maven project?

2) I also have an eclipse EJB 2.1 project that I want to move to maven.  The EJB runs in a server where several different applications are accessing it, including the two web projects mentioned above.  Should I create this EJB project as maven project?  If it is created as project, what is the proper way for those two web projects to reference it?

3) Is there a standard maven archetype for EJB2.1 project?

Thanks

Comment: possible duplicate of [Maven "Module" vs "Project" (Eclipse, m2eclipse plugin)](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2890341/maven-module-vs-project-eclipse-m2eclipse-plugin)

Comment: @Jarrod Roberson.  Yes, I saw that post when researching it.  It only explain what the diff between the two.  It does not give answer on my question on #1.  I need to create a module that referenced by two different web applications.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, there is nothing like an *"m2e project".* *m2e* is an Eclipse plugin that supports working with *Maven projects.*

Re 1) You're right. A project/module can have one parent only. But, assuming that *"java projects that are being referenced by two different web projects"* means that the web projects depend on the Java projects:

- [Dependence](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-dependency-mechanism.html): one project depending on functionality of others and
- [Inheritance](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-pom.html#Project_Inheritance): a child project inheriting POM declarations from a parent project and
- [Aggregation (or Multi-Module)](http://books.sonatype.com/mvnref-book//reference/pom-relationships-sect-pom-best-practice.html#pom-relationships-sect-multi-vs-inherit): an aggregating project comprising (sub-)modules

... are different things.

See also [POM Reference, POM_Relationships](https://maven.apache.org/pom.html#POM_Relationships).

Comment: @ Gerold.  Finally got a chance to read those links you provided.  I've a better understanding of how maven work now.  Complicated but will give it a try.  Thank you for your help.